# DJANGO ModelAdmin SQLLite error : DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend

Tags: django, distinct, django-queryset, modeladmin

My model is

```
class Contrat(models.Model):
    Procedure = models.ForeignKey(Procedure)
    Contrat_text = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Contrat_text

Class Document(models.Model):
    Contrat = Contrat.objects.order_by('Contrat_text').distinct('Contrat_text')
    isContrat = models.BooleanField(('Contrat'), default=True)
    isCdC = models.BooleanField(('Cahier des Charges'), default=False)
    isCR = models.BooleanField(('Cahier de Recette'), default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Contrat
```

and my admin model is:

```
class DocumentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        fields = ('Contrat', 'isContrat', 'isCdC', 'isCR')
        list_display = ('id','isContrat', 'isCdC', 'isCR')
        ordering = ('id',)

    admin.site.register(Document, DocumentAdmin)
```

but what I get is:

```
DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend
```

Somebody know how to create a model admin without error?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is with this line

```
Contrat = Contrat.objects.order_by('Contrat_text').distinct('Contrat_text')
```

.distinct() can't be used with sqlite3 so you will have to switch to something like postgres to use it or modify your query. Also [Each field in your model should be an instance of the appropriate Field class.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/models/#field-types) so you are incorrectly defining your Contrat model field.

Comment: @Welenofsky But I am using MySQL, why still has this issue?

Comment: @aircraft you need to remove 'contrat_text' in distinct

Comment: Contrat = Contrat.objects.order_by('Contrat_text').distinct()

Answer (score 1):

For mysql:
you can use `Model.objects.values_list('field').order_by('field').distinct()`